# getting 404 cannot find requestmapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

need your help,I am getting HTTP Status 404 when access this url

```
localhost:8080/SurakartaSmart/adm-ser/view-all
```

below is my controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/adm-ser")
public class adminController {
    @Autowired
    adminService serv;
    @RequestMapping(value="/view-all", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<adminModel>viewall()throws Exception{
        List<adminModel>data = null;
        try{
        data = serv.viewall();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.getMessage();
    }
        return data;
}
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>surakarta-smar</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

where lies the fault that I need to improve?

Comment: Please share spring-config.xml

Comment: are you scanning the package of the controller?

Comment: yes, <context:component-scan base-package="com.retribusi.solo.controller" />